# How can I cache and read fields on non instantiated prefabs?

Tags: unity, prefabs, object-pools

Let's say I have a very simple 2D square prefab that has a script like this attached to it:

```
public class Square : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject GameObject { get; private set; }
    public Transform Transform { get; private set; }
    public SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer { get; private set; }

    private void Awake() 
    {
        GameObject = gameObject;
        Transform = transform;
        SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to arrange groups of these squares with different positions and sprite colors, saving them as prefabs to be used by a spawner (with object pooling), sort of like this:

```
public class SquareSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Square[] squares;

    private ObjectPool<Square> pool;  

    public void Spawn(Vector2 position)
    {
        foreach (var square in squares)
        {
            /* Get a square prefab from object pool 
               (this will instantiate a Square prefab into the scene 
               if one does not yet exist) */
            Square pooledSquare = pool.Get();
            
            /* Set up the squares we got from the pool 
               to match the squares given to the squares array */
            pooledSquare.Transform.position = position + square.Transform.localPosition;
            pooledSquare.SpriteRenderer.Color = square.SpriteRenderer.Color;

            // etc.
        }          
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a spawning system that is easily visualizable using prefabs. Since object pooling is used, I don't know the configuration of the square I'll be getting back, so I always have to set the given squares' properties to match the desired configuration (this could be size, color, position, etc.).

The issue is that I can't read the properties from the `Square` prefabs that are not being instantiated (the ones I'm putting into the `Square[] squares` array) because the `Awake()` method only gets called upon instantiation into the scene.

Perhaps there's a better way for me to set all of this up, but I'm wondering if there's a way for me to cache the properties in the `Square` class so that I can read them whether the script is on a prefab and/or an instantiated `Square` in the scene. It would also be nice if I could use a custom editor to test things in edit mode, which has also been hindered by my inability to cache these fields.

Comment: Please do not name your variable the same as the type, so instead of using `GameObject GameObject` use at least `GameObject gameobject`

Comment: Did you consider assigning your game object, transform, and sprite renderer references in `OnValidate` rather than `Awake`, so the date is already available at edit time and does not need to wait for instantiation? Also, note that `MonoBehavíour` classes already have a reference to `.gameObject` and `.transform`, so there's no particular benefit to be had in making your own aliases/copies of these public properties.

Comment: @DMGregory I've never used `OnValidate`, but I could try that. Also, I've heard countless times that caching `gameObject` and `transform` was a good idea for the minor performance improvements if one is going to be calling those properties all the time (which I will be doing).

Comment: You might have heard that caching component references to avoid `GetComponent` calls is beneficial. Neither of these properties invokes `GetComponent` — `.transform` has its own accelerated path because it's needed so frequently. I'd suggest you measure to see whether it actually makes a significant difference before adding extra complication to your code based on hearsay.

Comment: @Zibelas Do you have a specific reason for this? The feedback here is mixed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095644/should-a-property-have-the-same-name-as-its-type

Comment: @DMGregory I just tried `OnValidate` in a test script, and while it works for reading the fields of my prefabs, it doesn't work when I want to read the fields on instantiated objects. Should I just use `Awake` together with `OnValidate` and cache in both spots?

Comment: Regarding capitalization, you'll notice that all of the Unity API is written with member fields and properties starting with a lowercase letter, so that's usually considered a more idiomatic style for Unity scripts interacting with that API. It keeps things consistent so you don't have to flip-flop conventions depending on whether you're accessing something built into Unity or something custom that you made. It also ensures there's never ambiguity about whether you're trying to access an instance member or static member, since those two will look different: `myType.foo` vs `MyType.bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: ensure the data you want to access is serialized and available in the saved version of the prefab.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class Square : MonoBehaviour
{
    [field:SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer { get; private set; }

    private void OnValidate() 
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
}
```

This will...

1. Ensure the object has a `SpriteRenderer` component when you add the `Square` component, if it didn't already, via the `RequireComponent` attribute.
2. Immediately call `OnValidate` when you edit the prefab in the inspector, caching a reference to that `SpriteRenderer`.

   (Technically here you could also use the `Reset` method which is called once when the component is added or manually reset to its defaults in the editor, rather than `OnValidate` which is called after every change or assembly reload in editor, as well as on entering play mode. But `OnValidate` is a bit more flexible if there's other stuff you want to set up that might *not* be available from the first moment the component is added. Note Philipp's caution from he comments that neither of these methods is called in the build, so use this only to set up data that you can serialize and load from disk already in the correct state)
3. Serialize that reference via the `field:SerializeField` attribute, so that it's saved with the prefab and available to read from the saved version without instantiating it.

I did not do this with the `gameObject` or `transform` members because those are already available to us in serialized prefabs through `MonoBehaviour` without needing to write any extra code of our own.

---

[Alex Hetherington has created a handy editor script that simplifies this common task of linking-up component references](https://twitter.com/FootnotesFuture/status/1473306357562552324). Now you can just add a `[Resolve]` attribute above the serialized component field you want to populate, and it will add a one-click button to populate the field (even populating an array of references), without you having to write your own initialization in `OnValidate()` or elsewhere. [Here's a link to the GitHub repository with this and other utilities you can add to your project](https://github.com/alexjhetherington/FootnoteUtilities).

Comment: The key point here is the [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) message method which gets called by the Unity editor every time there is a change in the editor. But remember that it does not get called in the build, so you still need to do the same stuff in Awake.

Comment: @Philipp You don't need to do the stuff shown here in `Awake` because the results of the last editor-time `OnValidate` call are already serialized and available in the saved version of the prefab read from disk. Now if this code included setup steps that were *not* reflected in the serialized data, then those would need to be performed after instantiation, or via a custom `Initialize()` method that you call as your game loads.